# List all rows in a Multiple Line Textbox c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve Ingredient_ID, Ingredient_Name and Ingredient Amount from an Ingredients table. I am trying to list them side by side in a list in a Multiple Line Textbox. So it will look like the following

```
orange | 1
apple  | 5
kiwi   | 2
```

In the database i have 20 unique ingredients, 14 of which link to the recipe id. What is happening is that its retrieving 14 rows of the first row.

For example:

```
steak | 1
steak | 1
steak | 1
```

etc...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["New"] != null)
            {               
                                if (Session["Basket"] != null)
            {
                ShoppingBasket.Visible = true;
                redPnl.Visible = false;
                RecipeID.Text += Session["Basket"].ToString();

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Ingredient Where Recipe_ID=@RecipeID", con);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@RecipeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RecipeID.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        IngredientsList.Text += dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() + " | " + dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString() + " | " + dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have multiple rows of data that matches Recipe_ID. So im hoping to retrieve several

Comment: inside the inner most if clause you need to to `foreach` through the rows to add the results of the query to the output text control.

Comment: @garglblarg can you show me an example please? to get an idea. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["New"] != null)
            {               
                if (Session["Basket"] != null)
                {
                    ShoppingBasket.Visible = true;                    
                    redPnl.Visible = false;                   
                    RecipeID.Text += Session["Basket"].ToString();

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Ingredient_Name, Ingredient_Amount From Ingredient Where Recipe_ID=@RecipeID", con);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@RecipeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RecipeID.Text;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    IngredientsList.Text = string.Empty;
                    for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count ;i++)
                    {
                        IngredientsList.Text += dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        IngredientsList[i].Text += " | " + dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + Enviornment.NewLine;
                        //dt.Clear(); :EDITED
                    }
                    dt.Clear();
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: better to use a Grid to display the result.

Comment: Hi, its just literally a textbox set to multiple lines. So i dont think it would work.

Comment: Ok, I am changing the answer accordingly, but better to use a Grid

Comment: I understand that, but what im going for is for the user to get a list of ingredients according to the selection. They are then able to edit the text by hand and export it... Thats the functionality plan

Comment: It works however its only retrieving 1 row, when it should retrieve 14. However it works what you have done, it just needs to somehow loop through and fetch them all. thank you

Comment: this might be why you are getting 1 row instead of 14 @DonaldBury

Comment: Works. Thank you both of you for being patient and helping me. @David

Answer (score 1):

You only see a single value because you're only *setting* a single value, right here:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    IngredientsList.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    IngredientsList.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    dt.Clear();
}
```

If you want all the rows from the query result, you have to loop over them and *append* them to the control.  Maybe something like this:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IngredientsList.Text += row.ItemArray[0].ToString() + " | " + row.ItemArray[1].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Formatting will be an issue, though.  This is more likely to produce something like this:

```
orange | 1
apple | 5
kiwi | 2
```

So you might need to throw in some string padding.  If you know what the width *should* be, then you can explicitly pad it.  Basically by replacing this:

```
row.ItemArray[0].ToString()
```

with this:

```
row.ItemArray[0].ToString().PadRight(6)
```

Just use whatever total width value you need.  If, on the other hand, you need to *calculate* the total width, then you'd need to examine the table records first to determine the widest value and use that.

There are a number of ways to potentially improve this.  Use a `StringBuilder` or `string.Format()` instead of directly concatenating values, for example.  Or perhaps make use of other controls for displaying the data, modifying the user experience a bit.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ItemArray' and no extension method 'ItemArray' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DonaldBury: Interesting.  You may need to use "DataRow row" instead of "var row" or something similar.  It's been a long time since I've had to use the old ADO objects, and strong typing was never really their thing.

Comment: I used dt.Rows[0].ItemArray and got it working. Now im stuck with another issues. Its retrieving the same row but 14 times. 14 times as there is 14 ingredient items

Comment: @DonaldBury: Sounds like your query is returning 14 records then.

Comment: Yeah but its only showing the top row14 times. It is not showing 14 individual rows

Comment: @DonaldBury: The results that you are describing strongly suggest that the data has 14 identical rows.  I can't really fix bad data, you will have to do that.

Comment: @DonaldBury: Then update the question with the code that you're using.  If you have done something different than what this answer suggests, you will need to show that.

Comment: @DonaldBury: You're not using the "row" variable anywhere.  You loop over the rows, but just explicitly use Row[0] every time.  The point of a loop is to use all the objects in a collection, not just the first one.

Comment: @DonaldBury: That's exactly what this answer demonstrates.  Take a look at the code posted in this answer.  The idea is to loop over the rows of data and *use each one* in the result.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var row in dt.Rows){
        IngredientsList.Text.Append(String.Format("{0}|{1}",row.ItemArray[0], row.ItemArray[1]));
    }
    dt.Clear();
}
```

something like that should do it

Comment: @SamGhatak well yes, the `if` is superfluous and the format string could be expanded but that's for the questioner to finalize and conform with the specific requirements. my post was just supposed to get him started on the solution x)